# Kalman Filter and Covariance Matrix

Tags: kalman-filter

In the Kalman filter, these equations represent the error on the state $x(k)$ a priori and a posteriori (discrete time).

\begin{align}
e_k^- &= x_k - \hat{x}_k^- \\
e_k &= x_k - \hat{x}_k
\end{align}

From these we get the a priori and a posteriori covariance matrices:

\begin{align}
P_k^- &= E\left[e_k^-\,{e_k^-}^\top\right] \\
P_k &= E\left[e_k\,{e_k}^\top\right]
\end{align}

The Kalman filter minimizes these matrices.
What i don't understand it what's the practical meaning of minimizing the covariance matrices. Why we want that the elements of vector $e_{k}$ (or $e^{-}_{k}$) are uncorrelated?

Answer (score 2):

The Kalman gain is computed as to minimizes the trace of $P_k$. The trace of $P_k$ equals the mean squared error of the estimation and since it is minimized by the optimal choice of the Kalman gain, the Kalman filter is called a minimum mean squared error estimator.

Also, if everything is linear and Gaussian, then $e_k$ is also Gaussian with zero mean. The expected power carried by a zero mean signal is also described by the trace of its covariance matrix, so the Kalman filter minimizes the power of the error variable.

Comment: Is minimizing the trace of *P <sub>k</sub>* also an optimal/good criterion for the *extended kalman filter*?